# How can I avoid escaping quotes when I export an org file to markdown?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, markdown

`"foo"` becomes `&ldquo;foo&rdquo;` when I run `org-md-export-as-markdown`

I just want it to export to `"foo"`. How can I fix this?